# background image pattern acting weird while scrolling in chrome/safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://testingprth.hostingsiteforfree.com/demo/

If you scroll the page in safari or chrome, you'll notice that the background pattern has some issues. I believe it's to do with the videoBG.js file as it works fine with a simple jpg background file.

Could anyone help/suggest which line to edit so i can have this pattern working? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by moving the `<div id="bgpattern"></div>` after the `<div class="videoBG">...</div>` in the markup.  Is that possible for you?

===EDIT===

I'm not sure you need a script to do this...  Sites I've implemented with background video just use the following markup.

```
<video id="videoplayer" poster="Static-Fall-Back-Image.jpg" autoplay="" loop="">
    <source src="Video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="Video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    <img src="Static-Fall-Back-Image.jpg" style="width:100%;">
</video>
```

with the following CSS:

```
#videoplayer {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

This certainly works on http://www.issuecentre.com which is a site I developed.

Comment: i'm sorry i don't get you. there's no <div class="videoBG"> anywhere in the page! Could you kindly give me more information? Thank you.

Comment: There is once it's been rendered (right click in chrome and click inspect element, you'll see it).  I have no idea of the method you are using (Never heard of videoBG.js but I assume it insert a div element with the class videoBG).  I assume you must tell it where to insert the video in the markup?  If so - make sure it's inserted into the markup before the background div.

Comment: Looks like i'm doing something wrong. 

yes, i just notice! videoBG seems to create multiple instances of body tag. Can't find any background video script that works either!! anyways, i tried inserting the codes as you've mentioned. it doesn't seem to work :( screenshot is attached for your info: http://s22.postimg.org/n79amo4m9/Screen_Shot_2013_08_29_at_7_50_52_PM.png

Comment: thank you so much. i did a few css tweaking to work on my original template and now with your code, everything works great. i don't have any reputation to vote for you :( please let me know if there's anything i can help.

Comment: Just accept the answer as correct - the little green tick will get me rep ;)

Comment: Done. Thank you once again :) :)

Comment: btw, any chances of loading the jpg only if the video is not supported? don't want to burden the users with extra 200kb on a poster loading. searched online but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: I *think* if you omit the "poster" attribute you'll get what you want; however - I wouldn't worry about it as it will be cached after the first load.  Also it's nice to have something displayed while the video loads.